# what determines the correct values for bridge rectifiers?

Tags: bridge

I want to fit led lighting in a model railway coach, how ever the + and - have to be correct for a led to work. If I use a bridge rectifier this will solve the problem. The track suplies 12 volts at 5amp for DC controlers and upto 20 volts at 5amps for DCC. Would a 1.5 amp 100 volts bridge rectifier be suitable for this job?

Answer (score 2):

> Would a 1.5 amp 100 volts bridge rectifier be suitable for this job?

More than enough in my opinion. Your LED load determines the current that flows thru the rectifiers and this might be only 100mA (5 x 20mA LEDs with series resistors). 1A diodes are an overkill IMO. 100V is OK but no less - I've read that 50V peaks can present themselves on the tracks when using DCC.

You mention DCC and I know this is an DC power supply with data superimposed (it makes it a high frequency AC square wave) to control the locos and lights. Just make sure that any bridge and lighting doesn't destroy the data signal superimposed on the supply - it's easy to do (I believe) if you have a bridge rectifier and load/capacitor. Killing the AC sq wave reversals is not really possible but screwing the rise/fall times might be a problem to anything decoding the DCC data.

Hey, I'm no expert but I do use DCC control on my model railway and I reckon you have to be a little bit careful. My recommendation is not use a "several micro farad" capacitor directly after the bridge

Answer (score 1):

Think for a second - does 1.5A sound like it can handle 5A? The supply can deliver 5A, so your bridge rectifiers should at least be able to handle that much. Another thing is your LED load may not draw very much, and for a model railway coach I suspect it will be less than 100mA or so. This means you could probably make the bridge much SMALLER than you expect, say each diode can just be a 1A rated through-hole diode. That may sound contradictory, but go for the expected load rather than trying to match the high power input supply.

The breakdown voltage (voltage ratings) should not need to be more than 1.5x the maximum expected voltage supplied, so a 30V rated diode used for the rectifier would be sufficient, and nice and small. The higher voltage ratings you go, the larger the packages are (for isolation etc).

The above recommendations are for DC polarity rectification, as you wanted for wire polarity-invariant connections from the train system to the LEDs. For AC rectification the recommendations are different, where the voltage rating for a full bridge rectifier should be minimum 1.5 x VAC and for a halfbridge rectifier should be 3 x VAC rated (for reverse breakdown).